# Modifying arrays with Operators and Iteration Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iterator

The function `a[a.size - (a >= 0)[::-1].argmax():] = 0` assigns 0 to the arrays if the array is equal to or less than 0, it also assigns 0 to the arrays that are behind it. In example `a` the function works fine it assigns 0 to third element till the last element. However in example `b` it does not do that even though the initial value is negative. How could i modify the function so that it gives me the desired result.

Example A

```
a = np.array([[  123.7   131.1 -4578.2 -4579.1 -4520.1 -4561.3 -4490.9 -4498.5 -4513.8
 -4550.9]])
a[a.size - (a >= 0)[::-1].argmax():] = 0
Output = [123.7 131.1   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. ]
```

Example B

```
b = np.array([-570.,  -593.37,   -286.59771,  -264.24308862])
b[b.size - (b >= 0)[::-1].argmax():] = 0
Output = [-570.,  -593.37,   -286.59771,  -264.24308862]
Desired Output = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I think the array a has one extra dimension since I copied your code and it didn't give me the output. You might edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a similar approach:

```
b[(b>=0).argmin():] = 0
```

(It also works for `a`)